Error deploying a Next.js page covered by withPageAuthRequired (Auth0)
I want to secure my layout.tsx in Next.js 14 by withPageAuthRequired from Auth0. So my file looks the following:
import { AppRouterPageRoute, withPageAuthRequired } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import AppNavigation from "./app-navigation";

async function AppLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row h-screen w-screen">
      <div className="w-1/5">
        <AppNavigation />
      </div>
      <div className="w-4/5 p-20">{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withPageAuthRequired(
  AppLayout as unknown as AppRouterPageRoute,
  {
    returnTo: "/app",
  }
);


When I run the app locally everything works as expected. But when trying to deploy to Vercel I get the following error:
Type error: Layout "app/(webapp)/app/layout.tsx" has an invalid "default" export:
  Type "AppRouterPageRouteOpts" is not valid.

